# How to insert list of values into null values of a column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, null

I am new to pandas. I am facing an issue with null values. I have a list of 3 values which has to be inserted into a column of missing values how do I do that?

```
In [57]: df
Out[57]: 
   a   b   c  d  
0  0   1   2  3  
1  0 NaN   0  1  
2  0 Nan   3  4 
3  0   1   2  5  
4  0 Nan   2  6  
In [58]: list = [11,22,44]
```

The output I want

```
Out[57]: 
   a   b   c  d  
0  0   1   2  3  
1  0   11  0  1  
2  0   22  3  4 
3  0   1   2  5  
4  0   44  2  6
```

Comment: what if you have more NaN values than elements in your list? (btw. don't redefine the built-in `list`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your list is same length as the no of NaN:

```
l=[11,22,44]
df.loc[df['b'].isna(),'b'] = l
```

---

```
print(df)

   a     b  c  d
0  0   1.0  2  3
1  0  11.0  0  1
2  0  22.0  3  4
3  0   1.0  2  5
4  0  44.0  2  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `stack` and assign the value then `unstack` back

```
s = df.stack(dropna=False)
s.loc[s.isna()] = l # chnage the list name to l here, since override the original python and panda function and object name will create future warning 
df = s.unstack()
df
Out[178]: 
     a     b    c    d
0  0.0   1.0  2.0  3.0
1  0.0  11.0  0.0  1.0
2  0.0  22.0  3.0  4.0
3  0.0   1.0  2.0  5.0
4  0.0  44.0  2.0  6.0
```